# image not display on block in grapesjs

Tags: reactjs, image, grapesjs

> Making a Block and Display Image on Block but not Displaying. but I set image HTTPS link it's displayed also. can I add CSS to the image?

```
  //contact page
                {
                    id:'contact',
                    attributes: { class:'gjs-block-contact'},
                    label: `<div>
                                <img src="./assets/images/contact-us.png" class="cus" alt="contact" >  
                            </div><br>
                            `,
                    category:'Pages',
                    content: `
                        <section class="col-mb-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-md-0 mb-5">
                                     <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                `,
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried but did not add an image through the `img` tag. so adding image using CSS.any other ways so share it.

```
.gjs-block-header1 {
height:150px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("./assets/images/header/header-1.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```